# Is there special name for this function ?, $f(n)$ = smallest $k$, s.t. $\log^k(n) \leq 1$

Tags: special-functions

$\log^k(n) = \log(\log(\log(...\log(n))));$

Let $f(n)$ = smallest $k$, s.t.  $\log^k(n) \leq 1$

Is there known name for function $f$ ?  Or it's an instance of some known function ?

Basically I want to know if anyone else also treating $O(f(n))$ as good as $O(1)$.

Comment: This is usually denoted $\log^*$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I suggest that you turn your comment into an answer, so that this question can be closed.

Comment: @user2145334: $f(n)$ tends to infinity, so $O(f(n))$ is weaker than $O(1)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO Ok, I’ve done so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) function, commonly denoted $\log^*(n)$.

It happens to come up from time to time in the analysis of various algorithms; while it grows extremely slowly, and is basically a constant for most practical purposes, it is still an unbounded function, and you cannot present it as being $O(1)$.